# How to calculate percentile in Java?

Tags: java, percentile

I am trying to calculate Percentile from the data sets which I have populated in a LinkedHashMap.

```
Key             Value
1               1
2               1
3               1
4               6
5               10
5               19
7               19
8               20
```

How can I get percentile of each value?
I am using following code which is not giving correct percentile I think.

```
float i = test.size();
float k = test.size();

if (test.size() > 1) {
    float  n = (i-1)*100/i;

    for (int j = 0; j <=i ; ) {
        if (i == 1) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        float  a = (i-1)*100/k;
        System.out.println("Percentile of lastvalue "+a);

        i--;
        System.out.println("Size of i "+i);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Bye");
}
```

If anyone can help me please help

i am looking output something like this

```
Percentile of lastvalue 83.333336

Percentile of lastvalue 66.666664

Percentile of lastvalue 50.0
Percentile of lastvalue 33.333332

Percentile of lastvalue 16.666666
```

Percentiile wil start countiion from highest vlaue in list

Comment: Is there an external range of `value` you want to use for calculating percentiles?  Or, is `1-20` the range?

Comment: value i  disply here is coming datnamic  it may be let or more

Comment: wnat to get percentile of  every values

Comment: Is your `LinkedHashMap` actually ordered in such a way that it is sorted by `value` ?

Comment: value is alreday sorted  now i wantot calculate   Percentile

Comment: Show expected output as it exactly maps to input observations.

Comment: i am geting correct out put what ever i did  but 1 vlau out put not  correct

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: you are using formula not correct   i think for percentile

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Guava's Quantiles to calculate quantiles\percentiles data -
https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/Quantiles.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, test.size() returns the number of entries in the LinkedHashMap, which is probably not what you want. If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate each values relative size (percentile) of the sum of all of the values. This is what my code snippet accomplishes.

Also, you have written the key 5 twice, which I believe you did not mean to do (LinkedHashMaps or hash tables in general don't support duplicate keys). I've therefore changed the last of the 5's to 6.

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class CalcPercentiles
{
  public static void calcPercentiles(LinkedHashMap hashMap) {
    int size = hashMap.size();

    List<Integer> value_list = new ArrayList(hashMap.values());

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += value_list.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(100 * value_list.get(i) / (float) sum);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    LinkedHashMap hashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    hashMap.put(1, 1);
    hashMap.put(2, 1);
    hashMap.put(3, 1);
    hashMap.put(4, 6);
    hashMap.put(5, 10);
    hashMap.put(6, 19);
    hashMap.put(7, 19);
    hashMap.put(8, 20);
    CalcPercentiles.calcPercentiles(hashMap);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1.2987013
1.2987013
1.2987013
7.7922077
12.987013
24.675325
24.675325
25.974026
```